# Getting a Type Mismatch error when passing SeriesCollection object

Tags: excel, vba

Already searched the web for this problem with no luck. I am using Excel 14.0 and even though I hate using VBA for charting purposes, I have no choice. I need to occasionally update literally dozens of charts. Excel just doesn't offer an easy way of doing this, for example a find replace on source data ranges.

Maybe I am getting too sophisticated for VBA. I know it has its limits, but I pass objects all the time without problems. Here is what I am trying to do. Seems simple enough. I can't seem to pass the SeriesCollection object. Tried ByRef, ByVal, both give Type Mismatch error. I even tried without the With/End With block. I also made sure it was the SeriesCollection argument throwing off the error. I guess I could just pass the chart object and an integer for the seriescollection, but that's too many variables imo.

```
Sub mcrMyCode1()
    With ActiveChart
        Call mcrSeriesMod(.SeriesCollection(1), "HD", "HO", "Avg", 34, 57)
    End With
End Sub
Sub mcrMyCode2()
    Call mcrSeriesMod(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1), "HD", "HO", "Avg", 34, 57)
End Sub

Sub mcrModSeries(ByRef SeriesMod As SeriesCollection, _
                ByVal sStCol As String, _
                ByVal sEndCol As String, _
                ByVal sTitle As String, _
                ByVal iXRow As Integer, _
                ByVal iYRow As Integer)            
    With SeriesMod
        .XValues = "=Sheet1!$" & sStCol & "$" & iXRow & ":$" & sEndCol & "$" & iXRow
        .Values = "=Sheet1!$" & sStCol & "$" & iYRow & ":$" & sEndCol & "$" & iYRow
        .Name = sTitle
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I seemed to have answered my own question. SeriesCollection is not an object but a method. At least that's what the VBA help says. So bizarre. So I changed the argument type to Series and that works. The object model for charts is so confusing. I hate it.

Comment: Do u get any points for answering your own question? LOL

Comment: If you ctually answer it you may get reputation